# Merging CSV with different time series in to a single one with python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Hi I have multiple data in csv files, the data is sampled with different at time like this:

File1.csv

```
hostid;Date;Value;
160761;2014-10-01 00:05:00;90
160761;2014-10-01 00:11:00;91
160761;2014-10-01 00:17:00;92
```

File2.csv

```
hostid;Date;Value;
160761;2014-10-01 00:08:22;89
160761;2014-10-01 00:13:50;93
160761;2014-10-01 00:14:54;92
```

FileN.csv

```
hostid;Date;Value;
160761;2014-10-01 00:00:55;89
160761;2014-10-01 00:06:50;93
160761;2014-10-01 00:08:54;92
160761;2014-10-01 00:14:55;89
160761;2014-10-01 00:15:50;93
160761;2014-10-01 00:16:50;92
```

How can I merge them in a single CSV interpolating the File1 and File2 with the time series of FileN?

If there is no data before a certain value I like to have the value NaN.

Example of output file is:

```
hostid;Date(FileN);Value(filen);Value(file1);Value(file2) 
160761;2014/10/01 00:00:55;89;NaN;NaN 
160761;2014/10/01 00:06:50;93;90,16;NaN 
160761;2014/10/01 00:08:54;92;90,50;89,01 
160761;2014/10/01 00:14:55;89;91,50;NaN 
160761;2014/10/01 00:15:50;93;91,66;NaN 
160761;2014/10/01 00:16:50;92;91,83;NaN
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to concatenate all the csv files into a single data frame? What is in the ```Value``` column? When you say interpolate, what do you want to interpolate and how? Maybe give a sample of the output you want, rather than just the headers

Comment: Yes I want to make a single dataframe. `Value`column is the sampled value of  that I want to concatenate. Linear interpolation is ok.

Comment: So do you wan the result to have a single ```Value``` column. Do the csv files share datetimes or are they all unique? What do you want to do with host id? Is it always 160761 or can it take different values? It would be a lot easier if you gave a sample of desired output

Comment: Hi, I have edit my question with the output file.